# Finding out the Version of Lotus Domino Server from Lotus Notes Client

Tags: email, email-server, lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I'm trying to verify the version of Lotus Domino server from a new client I installed, I installed Lotus notes 8.5 and the mail template is of the old 6.5, however I've been told we have the version 8, but my guess is in the mail cluster not all servers are using the new v8 template but just aren't upgraded yet. 
Would there be anywhere I can find in the logs or notes client where it will show connection details etc..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways to find the version of Domino running on a server:

- Open the Name and Address Book on server (usually, names.nsf), go to the Configuration > Servers > All Server Documents view (using left-hand navigator). You will see a list of all servers, and a column for each labeled "Domino Release"
- Open the main log database (usually, log.nsf) on the server. This has a series of log documents, ordered by timestamp. After the server re-starts, the log document will contain details from the startup, including the complete Domino release and hotfix number.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to open the Domino Directory (names.nsf in the root of your server's data directory)?

If so, do so then open the view "Server \ Servers".  This will appear in the navigator under "Configuration \ Servers \ All Server Documents", otherwise click on the View menu and select the option "Go to" and open the view from there.

The Domino version is in column 5 of the view (column 4 if you don't count the category column).

Comment: This worked for me and my ancient R5 Notes client, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The mail template version used needs not to be the same as the server version.

So the question is what do you exactly want? Newer Mail App? You can try File -> Application -> Replace design and replace it with newer.

Best is that you talk to your Notes Administrator, he may have reasons to stick with old design or something...

Comment: Can't replace the template as don't have rights too. The other problem is our IT is huge (Large Corp) and I guess finding the right sysadmin to change things is another challenge in it self!
I really want them to use a new mail app, even getting a newer template would be excellent

Comment: You can't use new template with old server AFAIK. Other than that I think booyaa is right - there is no way to know from a client. At least I've tried today to no avail and I have good contact with our Notes Admin.

Comment: @slovon, typically you can use a new template with an old server but some features may not be available.

Answer (score 0):

if you're a not an admin you won't be able to tell what version of domino you're using. if you had access to the console, you could've typed "show server" to see what version of domino you're running.

but slovon's right, talk to your admin and ask why you're on a 6.x mail template.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is to know Server Version, then above is fine. If the aim is to get latest template, try load convert on server console. Or open database replace design option--select the server which has 8Template, select the template and replace it.